# Can access some kernel32 functions with ctypes in 32 bit but not 64 bit

Tags: windows, python-3.x, 64-bit, ctypes, kernel32

I am trying to use [InterlockedExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx) from kernel32 in a 64 bit python application.

This is the code I would ideally like to have working:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

interlockedValue = ctypes.c_long(5)

print(interlockedValue.value)

locked = ctypes.c_long(68)
print(windll.kernel32.InterlockedExchange(byref(interlockedValue),locked))

print(interlockedValue.value)
```

However this is my ouput with 64 bit python 3.5.2:

```
C:\Users\Douglas Sexton\Source\Repos\SharedMemory\SharedMemory\Python>python interlocked3.py
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "interlocked3.py", line 10, in <module>
print(windll.kernel32.InterlockedExchange(byref(interlockedValue), locked))
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'InterlockedExchange' not found
```

32 bit works as I would expect though:

```
C:\Users\Douglas Sexton\Source\Repos\SharedMemory\SharedMemory\Python>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36\python.exe" interlocked3.py
5
5
68
```

I tried accessing from ordinal as well:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

interlockedValue = ctypes.c_long(5)

print(interlockedValue.value)

locked = ctypes.c_long(68)

print(windll.kernel32[868](byref(interlockedValue), locked))

print(interlockedValue.value)
```

This has the same output for 32 bit but for 64 bit this is the output:

```
C:\Users\Douglas Sexton\Source\Repos\SharedMemory\SharedMemory\Python>python interlocked.py
5
0
0
```

I have tried a few different ways to access InterlockedExchange from python 64 now and all seem to run into the same issue.  I have been able to use other kernel32 functions from python 64.  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Apparently in the x64 ABI, [`InterlockedExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683590) is only available as the compiler intrinsic [`_InterlockedExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockedexchange-intrinsic-functions).

Comment: BTW, for the Windows API it's better to use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` instead of `ctypes.windll.kernel32`. This avoids caching prototypes on the global `windll` object and also enables ctypes to protect the WinAPI last error value. In this case the last error value is available via `ctypes.get_last_error()`, and you can set it beforehand via `ctypes.set_last_error(value)`. For a failed call, raise an exception via `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for your comment.  I guess I could create a dll which is just a wrapper for InterlockedExchange and use that?

Comment: If you'll have to build a wrapper, you may as well partition the problem to move the related aspects into C/C++. CFFI and Cython make it easier to write an extension module and may be better for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up not needing this for now but I was able to create a wrapper dll for InterlockedExchange and use that successfully from a 64 process.